# how to select XML node with Attribute names

Tags: c#, xml

i get XML data like this:

```
<Persons>
    <Person Role="Writer">Jame</Person>
    <Person Role="Writer">Matt</Person>
    <Person Role="Producer">Ben</Person>
</Persons>
```

then i try :

```
Persons.SelectSingleNode("ns:Person Role=\"Writer\"", mng).InnerText;
```

this can no select the node. 
it says:

```
'ns:Person Role='Writer'' has an invalid token.
```

ns is namespace works fine with other nodes

Comment: Provided XML doesn't contain any namespace.

Answer (score 0):

using LINQ to XML

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
var nodes = doc.Root.Elements(e => e.Attribute.Value == "Writer");

List<string> values = nodes.Select(n => n.Value).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Persons.SelectSingleNode("ns:Person[@Role='Writer']", mng).InnerText;
```

is what you want.

If it was me I'd first get the node, the if it wasn't null get InnerText, just in case it didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `[@Role='']` to match on the attribute. Here's a full example from LINQPad:

```
var xml = "<Persons><Person Role=\"Writer\">Jame</Person><Person Role=\"Writer\">Matt</Person><Person Role=\"Producer\">Ben</Person></Persons>";
var xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.LoadXml(xml);
Console.WriteLine(
   xmlDoc.DocumentElement
         .SelectSingleNode(@"//Persons/Person[@Role='Writer']").OuterXml);
```